# HTML positioning with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a progress bar in the white space below the centered logo. But since I am using container-fluid I cant use "align-items-end" because for some reason it extends the container height more. Can someone tell me how I should change this so I can add a progress bar below the logo and not mess up the "Create" and "Explore" positioning? In this JSFiddle link, I have added the code I'm using.
https://jsfiddle.net/mrwadepro/zzf5j3fm/13/

Below is the progress bar I'm trying to add

```
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="row">
   <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
</div>
  </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, the progress bar is supposed to go between the logo and the words `create/explore`?

Comment: @WebDevBooster I want it below the Explore and Create links. When I use align-items-end it create a longer row below, it creates that extra whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You had a Bootstrap `.row` immediately nested within another `.row`. You should never ever do that. When nesting a `.row` must always be followed by at least one Bootstrap column. And besides, nesting is totally unnecessary in this case.

You are also using a lot of unnecessary custom css. Unnecessary because those tasks can be done by using native Bootstrap 4 classes. When you introduce unnecessary custom css hacks, you'll inevitably need more custom css hacks to fix the problems caused by the original css hacks.

Here's a clean code snippet that does the job without needing any custom css and without the `align-items-end` class (click "run code snippet" below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col text-center">
           <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/29kpg7p.png" width="100" height="140">
       </div>
   </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" name="redirectCreate" onClick="redirectCreate()">
                <h1 class="text-center">
                    Create</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-center">
            <a href="#" name="redirectExplore" onClick="redirectExplore()">
                <h1 class="text-center">
                    Explore</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">25%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```